# Проблемы с запуском локального сервера

Tags: php, mysql, sql, openserver, xampp

Проблема состоит в запуске локального сервера, будь то OpenServer, то XAMPP.
Ошибка, по совместительству моя проблема, состоит в занятом порте. Как это исправить? Возможно ли как то освободить порт, либо же перекинуь локальный сервер на другой порт?
**АХ, да, у меня установленный MySQL отдельно**

[image: Проблемы с MYSQL на XAMPP]
[image: Проблемы с MYSQL на OpenServer]

Comment: дак если встроенный mysql не нужен, то отключите его, или измените используемый порт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В OpenServer в настройках Вы можете поменять порты всех модулей на какие захотите. Поменяйте MySQL, например, на 3307.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]